# How do i retrieve and add child node to a selected category using linq-to-xml from this structure?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'd like to add "Contact" to "Contacts" based on the selected category by the user. Let's assume the user selects "Friends" from the combobox, how will i add to the selected category.

```
<PhoneContacts>
  <Categories>
    <Category Name="Colleagues">
      <Contacts />
    </Category>
    <Category Name="Friends">
      <Contacts />
    </Category>
  </Categories>
</PhoneContacts>


Fields to be added is this
<Contact>
  <fullname>joe</fullname>
  <phoneno>123456</phoneno>
  <address>stack overflow</address>
</Contact>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with LINQ to XML.  You'll want to create a new `XElement` with the contact information in it and then add it as a child of the `Contacts` element in the proper category.  For simplicity I recommend using a method to create the contact `XElement`, and then simply add it to the XML.  It would look something like this:

```
public XElement CreateContact(string name, string phone, string address)
{

    XElement contact = new XElement("Contact", 
                           new XElement("fullname", name),
                           new XElement("phoneno", phone),
                           new XElement("address", address));

    return contact;
}
```

Then you can add it with something like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("contacts.xml");

string category = "Friends";
string name = "joe";
string phone = "123456";
string address = "stack overflow";

xDoc.Descendants("Contacts")
    .Where(x => x.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value == category)
    .Single()
    .Add(CreateContact(name, phone, address));

xDoc.Save();
```

The code above creates an `XDocument` (xDoc) by loading the XML file.

The LINQ statement selects the correct `Contact` node based on the parent node's `Name` attribute matching the category variable (also note that it expects to have only a single match).  Then it adds a new `Contact` node group via the returned `XElement` from `CreateContact`.

It then saves the updated XML file.

The new XML will look like this:

```
<PhoneContacts>
  <Categories>
    <Category Name="Colleagues">
      <Contacts />
    </Category>
    <Category Name="Friends">
      <Contact>
        <fullname>joe</fullname>
        <phoneno>123456</phoneno>
        <address>stack overflow</address>
      </Contact>
    </Category>
  </Categories>
</PhoneContacts>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out